# Can't login after Pantheon desktop installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pantheon

I wanted to try the Pantheon DE on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed it based on this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pantheon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux-desktop

After the reboot I changed it to Pantheon desktop but I wasn't able to login. Black screen for a few seconds and after the sound of unsuccessful login it went back to the login screen.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the login screen to LightDM (which is used by elementary OS).

Comment: How do i do that? I know that i installed lightdm though...

Comment: Installed yes, but is it in use? Use "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm" and select lightdm fron there, then reboot.

Comment: @dtravlos to change display manager, do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` on a terminal window, then choose lightdm and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt upgrade elementary-desktop lightdm pantheon-greeter
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
reboot
login
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches

sudo apt upgrade elementary-desktop lightdm pantheon-greeter

sudo apt update

sudo pat upgrade

reboot

login